# FTDI Basic Breakout - 5V

Tags: basic, breakout, arduino

Can this board be used to upload sketches to the Arduino. I tried by hooking the TX port on the FTDI Basic Breakout  to RX port(Pin 2 on the Arduino) and RX port to pin 3 on the Arduino. But so far I am not abl to upload anything.

The driver for the board loads fine.

Thanks for any feed back.

Comment: Are you pressing the reset button on the Arduino immediately before you download?

Comment: If you connect the DTR pin of the breakout board to the RESET pin on the atmega through a 100nF capacitor there's no need to press the reset button to upload sketches.

Answer (score 5):

As Joby Taffey suggests, the rx & tx pins of the AVR are 2 & 3 respectively, but on the Arduino headers they are pins 0 & 1. You also want to connect DTR to the reset pin of the arduino to enable automatic programming.

```
  FTDI        Arduino
Breakout        (5V)

     GND <--> GND
     CTS <--> (not connected)
      5V <--> 5V (if you want the breakout to power the arduino)
     TXO <--> RX (pin 0)
     RXO <--> TX (pin 1)
     DTR <--> RESET (possibly through a 100nF cap*)
```

On the FTDI TTL232R cable, DTR is not present so you have to manually reset the board before flashing. By default the Arduino will stay in the bootloader for 6-8s, but some boards rely on the automatic reset and have much shorter timeouts (0.25s say). For these boards, set `upload.verbose = true` in your Arduino conf file, and learn to time the reset the moment the software attempts to flash the board.

[* Arduino Wiki](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove)

Answer (score 3):

This board can be used to connect to the Arduino and transmit serial data, yes. I don't know much about how the Arduino loads sketches, but here's some suggestions:

Check your pins for TX and RX, [this diagram](http://profmason.com/?p=611) suggests that they might be labelled "pin 0" and "pin 1". But, this may depend on your make/model of Arduino.

[image: http://profmason.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/arduinopins.jpg]
<sub>(source: [profmason.com](http://profmason.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/arduinopins.jpg))</sub>

Check that the FTDI breakout's Ground is connected to the Arduino Ground pin.

Check that the Arduino is powered up.